# Can't edit in-app purchase in iTunes Connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My in-app purchase was rejected and now in 'Developer Action Needed'. However I can't seem to edit any of the fields.
In the meanwhile I've resubmitted another binary but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer. It says on the top of the page:

```
We’re making changes to auto-renewable subscriptions. 
You will not be able to create or edit auto-renewable subscriptions 
during this time.`
```

Hopefully this is resolved soon by Apple...